# ASPxGridView and Eval(string) method

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm trying to add column to ASPxGridView which would have link to other page:

```
  <Columns>
        ...
        <dxwgv:GridViewDataColumn Caption=" " VisibleIndex="10">
            <DataItemTemplate>
                <dxe:ASPxHyperLink ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" NavigateUrl="../Category/Elements/<%# Eval("Id").ToString() %>/Edit"/>
            </DataItemTemplate>
        </dxwgv:GridViewDataColumn>
    </Columns>
```

But I get error:

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

when I used ' ' instead " " the link href property is "../Category/Elements/<%# Eval("Id").ToString() %>/Edit"

Comment: Looks like you have a good answer already, but I think it might also work if you just change the outer quotes to single, I know in some cases that works, just not sure about this one.  For sure double-quotes inside double-quotes pretty much never works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can put databinding elements into the middle of the attribute value. The entire value needs to be within the `<% %>`:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "../Category/Elements/" +  Eval("Id").ToString() + "/Edit" %>'
```

I'm not sure with UI library you're using, but usually the `Eval()` allows a string format parameter. This would be preferable to the string concatenation approach. You might be able to do:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id", "../Category/Elements/{0}/Edit") %>'
```